# Jetpack Compose surface add custom shadow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

[image]

I am trying to develop a custom toolbar in jetpack compose but its shadow is applying to four sides but I want to achieve 3 side shadow(don't needed in top)

```
Surface(
    shape = RectangleShape,
    color = toolBarBackground(),
    elevation = 12.dp,
) {
    ...
}
```

I have tried custom shape, but the problem is path must be closed. I have done a simple tick as follows to overcome that but not working(component size itself changing).

```
private val CustomThreeSideShape = GenericShape { size, _ ->
    moveTo(0f, -100f)
    lineTo(0f, size.height)
    lineTo(size.width, size.height)
    lineTo(size.width, -100f)
    lineTo(0f, -100f)
    close()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not yet supported, star [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160665122) for updates.

Meanwhile you can use this hack with [`Modifier.drawWithContent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).drawWithContent(kotlin.Function1)) combined with [`DrawScope.clipRect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope).clipRect(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ClipOp,kotlin.Function1)):

```
val padding = 20.dp
val density = LocalDensity.current
Surface(
    shape = RectangleShape,
    color = Color.White,
    elevation = 12.dp,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(padding)
        .drawWithContent {
            val paddingPx = with(density) { padding.toPx() }
            clipRect(
                left = -paddingPx,
                top = 0f,
                right = size.width + paddingPx,
                bottom = size.height + paddingPx
            ) {
                this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
            }
        }
) {
    Text(
        "Hello",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Here shadow has a problem it is using our component's internal space. Adjacent components have a padding margin.

Comment: @EbinJoy I don't understand. If this solution doesn't work for you, add details to your question.

Comment: In my understanding, the shadow should be rendered over the component that resides below the toolbar component, not inside our component's padding.

In your solution, we are using  "20 dp" padding and the shadow was drawn there.

Comment: actually you can take a bigger value than an actual padding, it's not gonna draw anything extra